# Remove line from a file which is named in another

Tags: command-line, grep, text-processing, awk

I have the following list:

```
NM_000014 3
NM_000015 0
NM_000016 0
NM_000017 0
NM_000018 0
NM_000019 28
NM_000020 0
NM_000021 0
NM_000022 0
NM_000023 0
NM_000024 8
NM_000025 0
NM_000026 0
```

And I have another file with just the first column:

```
NM_000031
NM_000032
NM_000033
NM_000034
NM_000022
NM_000035
NM_000036
NM_000037
NM_000023
NM_000038
NM_000039
NM_000040
NM_000041
NM_000042
```

I want to remove the whole lines of the first file that are named as the second. In that case the output file will be:

```
NM_000014 3
NM_000015 0
NM_000016 0
NM_000017 0
NM_000018 0
NM_000019 28
NM_000020 0
NM_000021 0
NM_000024 8
NM_000025 0
NM_000026 0
```

(removing NM_000022 and NM_00023 with its corresponding values)

Thanks!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$0]; next}; {if ($1 in a) next}; 1' f1.txt f2.txt
```

Input the file with just a single column as the first argument, and the one to check for (first column) membership as the second argument.

- `NR==FNR {a[$0]; next}`, here `NR==FNR` will only be true for the first file, then we are saving each line into array `a` so that we can do membership test for the first argument of the second file, then we are going to the next line without any further operation on the second file
- `{if ($1 in a) next}; 1` will be executed only for the second file, the one to check, here we are checking if the whitespace separated first argument is in the array `a`, if present then going to the next line otherwise printing the whole line.

**Example:**

```
$ cat f1.txt 
NM_000031
NM_000032
NM_000033
NM_000034
NM_000022
NM_000035
NM_000036
NM_000037
NM_000023
NM_000038
NM_000039
NM_000040
NM_000041
NM_000042

$ cat f2.txt 
NM_000014 3
NM_000015 0
NM_000016 0
NM_000017 0
NM_000018 0
NM_000019 28
NM_000020 0
NM_000021 0
NM_000022 0
NM_000023 0
NM_000024 8
NM_000025 0
NM_000026 0

$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[$0]; next}; {if ($1 in a) next}; 1' f1.txt f2.txt
NM_000014 3
NM_000015 0
NM_000016 0
NM_000017 0
NM_000018 0
NM_000019 28
NM_000020 0
NM_000021 0
NM_000024 8
NM_000025 0
NM_000026 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `sed` with a Bash loop.

This command modifies `file1` in place (creating a backup `file1.bak`), removing every line that starts with any line from `file2`:

```bsh
while read line ; do sed -i.bak "/$line.*/d" file1 ; done < file2
```

Answer (score 1):

How is with 'grep' command here : )

```
grep -Fvf oneColumnedFile listFile > outfile
```